How to update blog post categories in WordPress?
I need to update a couple blog post categories, and the changes I applied are not working. I edited the category name on the back end under posts/categories, then went to the main blog page and edited the category in the text box on the main blog page. That change took, but doesn't extend to the other blog pages when clicking to other category pages. Also now when I click on the new category I get a 'no results found' error, even though blogs are assigned to that category. Any help would be appreciated!
